# Can not run Django project

Tags: python, django

I´m having a problem running my old django project. Its giving an error after i run py manage.py.
I tryed to use the command py manage.py makemigrations

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\Downloads\LES-fosquito\LES-fosquito\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 420, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in populate
app_config.ready()
File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
self.module.autodiscover()
 File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
 File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
 File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ricardo martins\Downloads\LES-fosquito\LES-fosquito\processes\admin.py", line 4, in <module>
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce'
```

Comment: try installing tinymce, `pip install django-tinymce-4`

Comment: you where right

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `TinyMCE` library in your code? If you are trying to run it locally, try to see if you have the correct dependencies installed, and if it is not needed you can simply remove the import statemnt.